# In Laravel 5.1 Images are Loaded in local but Not Loaded in Server from Database

Tags: laravel

I try to view a images in 
server side. but it does not shows the images. but if i run in local means it will works. kindly provide any idea

Comment: Open on server and right click on missing image. Check the image path and post the path. Also post how do you save the image uri. You are most likely saving image with wrong path (something like localhost/path-to-my-image.png).

Comment: Where are your images stored? Are you using absolute paths or relative paths? It sounds like dbr is on the right track here...

Comment: I got a solution for this problem

Comment: Thanks for your response dbr and james.

Comment: I add asset in url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi use asset helper method to load your images, css and javascript files properly for example in your public directory you have another directory name img which contain images you can load like this

```
asset('img/image.jpg')
```

please read laravel doc for more information for helper method 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-asset

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `{{URL::to('/')}}/images/image.jpg`  without `public` keyword in path.